# Incrementing version numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, int

I'm trying to do a version number update on files in CVS.

My initial logic was to update a float (1.1 --> 1.2 --> 1.3) which worked fine until I get to 1.9, then it updates to 2.0.

I'm trying to update to 1.10 with this logic, but it's throwing an error when I try to increment the x in 1.x (ver[1] += 1).

```
def replace_string():
    with open(filename) as f:
        found = False
    #for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1):
        for line in f:
            if re.search("CVS Header", line):
                print 'Old Line \n' + line

                ####################################################################################
                #  Below logic:                                                                    #
                #  if length of revision number is 4 characters (e.g. 1.15) then increment by 0.01 #
                #  else if it is 3 characters (e.g. 1.5) then increment by 0.1                     #
                ####################################################################################

                if len(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) == 4:
                    ver = line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]
                    ver = [int(x) for x in ver.split('.')]
                    ver = '{0[0]}.{0[1]}'.format(ver)
                    ver[1] += 1
                    print ver
                    new_line = str.replace(line, line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0], ver)
                    print new_line

                elif len(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) == 3:
                    ver = line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]
                    ver = [int(x) for x in ver.split('.')]
                    ver = '{0[0]}.{0[1]}'.format(ver)
                    ver[1] += 1
                    print ver
                    new_line = str.replace(line, line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0], ver)
            ###
                newer_line = str.replace(new_line, line.split("$Author: ")[1].split()[0], username)
                newest_line = str.replace(newer_line, line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[0], today)
                current_line = str.replace(newest_line, line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[1], time)
                found = True
                print 'New Line \n' + current_line

    if not found:
        print "No CVS Header exists in %s" % filename  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #args = parser.parse_args()
    replace_string()
```

Comment: Stack trace, line number?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git.py", line 78, in <module>
    replace_string()
  File "git.py", line 58, in replace_string
    ver[1] += 1
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Even if you manage to overcome the `int`-`str` conversion part, strings are immutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
ver, rev = str(1.9).split('.')
ver + '.' + str(int(rev)+1)  # result: '1.10'
```

With this, you could get rid of the check for the amount of digits present, as long as the input is always a string. In my example it is not, that's why I'm converting 1.9 to string, but it will fail here if used on the floating point number `1.10` rather than the string `'1.10'`. But you don't have to worry about that, because your input

```
line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]
```

is a string already.

Comment: Hi Oliver, can you explain how that ver, rev assignment is working? This seems to work but I'm trying to understand how. Are you assigning two variables to each part of the 1.x. So ver = 1 and rev = 9?

Comment: @user3495404, yes I am. In Python, this is called "[tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)".

Comment: Awesome, new to Python and was not aware of that. In what types of scenarios can you use tuple unpacking? When you're splitting strings apart?

Comment: @user3495404, any time you want to return more than a single value from a function, to start.

Comment: You can use it anytime when the result of an operation (e.g. a function) is a sequence (like a tuple or a list). Check the link from the tutorial that I've added now.

Comment: To avoid crashing with other version numbers, you might consider: `ver, rev = '1.9'.split('.', 3)[:2]`; that way you also work with `'1.9.3'` or `'1.3.9.15'`. The `3` -- putting a maximum limit on the number of items to split out -- is optional, since we're taking only the first two at the end, but a very minor performance enhancement.

Comment: ...mind you, if you always wanted to increment only the last component of the version string, rather than always incrementing the minor version and dropping anything after it, that would be a different algorithm (and `rsplit('.', 2)` would be useful), but that requires a more complete spec in terms of desired behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, true and correct improvements suggested. But, as you mention, the given solution will depend on a good specification of the desired behavior.