# python subtracting multiple decimal places

Tags: python

is it possible in python to somehow subtract using multiple decimal places like in version numbers.

for example,

8.0.18 attempting to find a previous version of 8.0.17

any way or method to subtract 1 to get 8.0.17?

i was thinking of regex and pulling out the 18 and subtracting 1 then make myself a variable from the 8.0. and add 17 back to it :), something like this

```
version_found = "8.0.18"
version = re.search('^\d.\d\d.(\d\d)$', version_found).group(1)
prev_version = int(version) - 1
```

so prev_version would end up being 17, then i could convert back to a string and take it on to 8.0.
but was wondering if there something method i don't know about or am not considering? thanks

Comment: how it should subtract `8.10.0` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing version numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868137/incrementing-version-numbers-in-python), oh my bad it's `Decrementing`, but possibly related -_-

Comment: possibly helpful library [semantic_version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/semantic_version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tiny little script I wrote, it should be fairly easy to implement in your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

version = "8.0.18"
version = version.split(".")
if int(version[-1]) > 0:
    version[-1] = str(int(version[-1]) - 1)
    version = '.'.join(version)
    print(version)
else:
    print("Error, version number ended in a zero!")
```

This works by splitting the string into a list on each period, resulting in `["8", "0", "18"]`. Then it gets the last element in the list by accessing index -1. Then we subtract 1 from the value of that index and assign it back to the same index. Lastly, join the list into a string with periods in between each element then print the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be count the number of periods in the string and split the text at the specific period you'd like it to subtract at. Then you'd have to turn the string into an integer, subtract 1 from that integer then readd it to the version number.

There are several ways of doing this but thats the way I'd do it. Also keep it in a function so you can call it multiple times at different points of periods.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Steampunkery

```
version = "6.4.2"
nums = version.split(".")

skip = 0 # skip from right, e.g. to go directly to 6.3.2, skip=1

for ind in range(skip,len(nums)):
    curr_num = nums[-1-ind]
    if int(curr_num) > 0:
        nums[-1-ind] = str(int(curr_num) - 1)
        break
    else:
        nums[-1-ind] = "x"

oldversion = '.'.join(nums)
print(oldversion)
```

Sample outputs:

```
8.2.0 --> 8.1.x
8.2.1 --> 8.2.0
8.0.0 --> 7.x.x
0.0.0 --> x.x.x
8.2.0 --> 8.1.0  (with skip=1)
```

Comment: No offense, but that is a very hard read. You may want to separate some bits onto different lines for readability.

Comment: @Steampunkery True, but yeah we thought about the same idea. Does not solve: **how it should subtract 8.10.0 ?** however

Comment: True, it may not subtract 8.10.0, but your answer does get the job done, just checked :)

Comment: @Steampunkery I'm gonna delete my answer. But look at it for one second. I think we need to account for negative numbers and print that

Comment: Hmm. Yeah. Negatives. I'll put that into mine. Why are you deleting yours? It's a good answer!

Comment: @Steampunkery Ok, my answer is back! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
version = "8.0.18"
index = version.rindex(".") + 1
version = version[:index] + str(int(version[index:])-1)
```

Just use rindex to find your last period.
Then, convert everything after that to a number, subtract one, turn it back into a string, and you're done.

This becomes more complicated if you want any value other than the last version number.  You'd have to rindex from the location that is returned each time.  E.g., to change the value after the "second from last" (i.e. first) decimal place, it gets uglier:

```
start_index = version.rindex(".")
for _ in range(1,1):
    end_index = start_index
    start_index = version.rindex(".", end=end_index)

version = version[:start_index+1] + 
    str(int(version[start_index+1:end_index])) + 
    version[end_index:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = version.split('.')            # make a list from individual parts

last_part = lst.pop()               # returns the last element, deleting it from the list
last_part = int(last_part) - 1      # converts to an integer and decrements it
last_part = str(last_part)          # and converts back to string

lst.append(last_part)               # appends it back (now decremented)

version = '.'.join(lst)             # convert lst back to string with period as delimiter
```