# Set Azure Pipelines build number dynamically?

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, pypi

I'm facing the following scenario:

I have a pipeline in Azure Pipelines which builds a Python package. As known, a Python package is defined by a `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` file, in which there's the `version` field. The version is in the form `major.minor.revision`.

When I publish the PyPI package to the repository (in this case it's hosted in Artifactory, but that really doesn't matter for the manner of sake), I want to publish it with the version number, appended with a running number that uniquely identifies this package.

So for example, if my setup.py now contains `1.2.3`, and the developers didn't change this number and ran the build several times, I want my packages to be numbered

- `1.2.3.0`
- `1.2.3.1`

etc., until one of the developers will change it to `1.2.4`, or `1.3.0`, etc. and then I want to zero the build number, so the next package will be  numbered `1.2.4.0` or `1.3.0.0`.

The basic and most strict requirement here is that whenever a developer will run `pip install my-package`, they will get the latest version of the package.

#### Possible solution

It is possible to do this (partially in pseudo-code):

```
name: $(Rev:r)
...
script: |
   version=$(extract version from setup.py)
   package_version=$(append the build number to version)
   sed -i 's/<version>/<package_version>/'
   push pypi package
```

This will keep a running build number from 0 to infinity, ensuring uniqueness and order of the published packages.

The only problem is that the $(Rev:r) will not be set to zero when someone changes the version in the `setup.py` file.

Is there any other way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever consider using [GitVersion](https://gitversion.net/) to properly provide versioning to your repo? There's also an [Azure DevOps Task](https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/build-servers/azure-devops) and the configuration is straightforward.

GitVersion can rely on custom rules and it uses git tags to help developers identify a version change in a standard way.

Then, if you feel brave enough you can then start to investigate [conventional-commit](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint) to give full flexibility to the team to decide which kind of version change you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to meet your need. You can refer to the following ideas:

1. Create a variable group. Create a variable "OldVersion" to represent the previous version, for example, the initial value is "1.0.0". Create another variable "BuildNumber" to represent the number of builds, with an initial value of 0.
2. Get the current version of the package from setup.py. For the convenience of description, the current version is represented by "NewVersion".
3. If "OldVersion" and "NewVersion" are equal, the value of "BuildNumber" is incremented by one. Then publish the package with the version of "NewVersion.BuildNumber".
4. If "OldVersion" and "NewVersion" are not equal. Set the value of "OldVersion" to the value of "NewVersion" and the value of "BuildNumber" to 0. Then publish the package with the version of "NewVersion.BuildNumber".

To update variable groups, you can use this REST API [Variablegroups - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedTask/Variablegroups/Update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) or the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#update-variables-in-a-variable-group).

Answer (score 0):

If I understard well the case, your question could be whether to add the build number. One of the options is to ask the developers to a tag to the pull request. And once the PR is merged, depends on the tag value, you can decide whether to add the build number.

Nevertheless, you need to let the developer to add or set sth. in the pipeline.

And by the way, version number like `1.2.3.0` is not semver compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Git Hooks** to enforce best practice

If someone forget (in this case) to bump up the version you can enforce operation during `pre-commit` events combined with your bump-up logic

Enable `pre-commit`
https://github.com/observing/pre-commit

Your bump-up logic [increase-last-digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868137/incrementing-version-numbers-in-python)

Example:

```
def bump_up(version):
  version = version.split('.')
  version[-1] = str(int(version[-1]) + 1)
  return '.'.join(version)
```